# Is it possible to establish a secure connection with a user, even by redirecting to HTTPS?

Tags: security, redirect, https, man-in-the-middle

So this is a somewhat broad question, I know, but I'm hoping someone who is wiser than I can provide a summary answer that can help wrap up all of the ins and outs of SSL for me.

Recently I watched a video of Moxie Marlinspike giving a presentation at BlackHat, and after the hour was up, I thought to myself, "It doesn't really matter what I do. There's always a way in for a determined hacker."  I recall his final example, in which he demonstrated how even using a redirect when the user typed in an HTTP address to go directly to HTTPS, there is still an opportunity in that transition for an attacker to insert himself via MITM.

So if browsers always default to HTTP, and users very rarely enter an HTTPS address directly in the address bar, then an attacker who is listening for accesses to Bank X's website will always have an opportunity during the HTTP -> HTTPS redirect to gain control.  I think they have to be on the same network, but that's little consolation.  Seems like Marlinspike's point was that until we go straight HTTPS as a standard rather than an alternative, this will always be a problem.

Am I understanding this correctly?  What is the point in redirecting to HTTPS if an attacker can use MITM during the transition to gain control?  Does anyone have any clue as to preventative measures one might take to protect himself?  Would redirecting via javascript that obfuscates the HTTPS links (so they can't be stripped out in transit) be of any help?  Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what is problem? So I open http:// securesite.com, and it redirects me to https:// securesite.com, hacker is on the same network as me, so what now? How hacker can get my data if server redirects instantly, without showing any content?

Comment: @VASoftOnline: The hacker can intercept the initial HTTP request and prevent the redirect in the first place.

Comment: Ok, it prevents to redirect; what now? I see that I am not on https:// securesite.com where I supposed to go, so I see that I am hacked, it is not good, but I don't loose anything; now I go and call police. It is more dangerous for hacker to do that than to me, isn't it?

Comment: @VASoftOnline: You see that; most users don't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to tell the browser that your site must always be accessed using HTTPS.

As long as the browser's first HTTP connection is not attacked, all future connections will go directly over HTTPS, even if the user doesn't type HTTPS in the address bar.

Comment: But if an attacker is set up to monitor and automatically intercept any connection headed to, say, Paypal on the initial HTTP connection, then he will find an open door with 99.9% of users, who don't type in https, right?  Seems like that initial connection is a critical weakness that there's no good defense against, if someone happens to be snooping.

Comment: On the other hand, I like the idea of HSTS, but then that would upset users, to have to type in the https.  Seems like we need a change in thinking about security.  Maybe SSL should be the standard when you type in a web address, and you should be able to explicitly mark certain elements (i.e. massive media files) to send in the clear.  Maybe we need a complete rethinking of things.

Comment: @user1630830: Hopefully, the initial connection will happen safely in the user's home.

Answer (score 0):

There are no actually any information leak in HTTP/HTTPS redirect if implemented properly on server side (i. e. if all dangerous cookies are marked as "HTTPS only" and inaccessible for JavaScript).
Of course, if end user doesn't know anything about security, it can be hacked, but from the other hand, if you user doesn't know even basic security rules and there are not system administrator who will explain it to user, it is possible to hack such user in so many ways that HTTP to HTTPS redirect problems is not really trouble.
I saw many users who downloaded and run unknown EXE files from server just for promise to "win 1000000 dollars", which is also a good way to hack them (even better than to exploit redirection, if you run as EXE in user computer, you are already king here and can steal any user cookies under default security settings).
So, if user collaborates with hacker and helps hacker to hack his own computer, yes, such user will succeed to be hacked, but security is about professionals who ready to protect himself and not about user who may be publishes his PayPal cookies somewhere on Blogpost and after that surprized that he is hacked.